# Using the Schwarz Lemma to prove a Bound

Tags: complex-analysis

This exercise is from Titchmarsh's *Theory of Functions*:

> Let $f(z)$ be regular inside and on the unit circle, $|f(z)|\leq M$ on the circle, and $f(a)=0$ where $|a|<1$, then $$|f(z)|\leq M\cdot\left|\frac{z-a}{\bar{a}z-1}\right|$$inside the circle.

I've had two thoughts toward solving this problem. The first was to define $$\varphi_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{\bar{a}z-1}.$$ This maps $0$ to $a$, so if we take the composition and divide by $M$, we get a map from $\Bbb D$ (the unit disc) into $\Bbb D$ with $g(0)=0$. This told me $|f\circ\varphi_a(z)|\leq|z|$, which doesn't seems very helpful. Next, I thought since $f$ vanishes at $a$, we know $f(z)/(z-a)$ is a holomorphic function, so it takes its maximum on the boundary. Using what we have, I came up with $$\left|\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\right|\leq\frac{M}{|z-a|}\leq\frac{M}{|z|-|a|}=\frac{M}{1-|a|}.$$This seemed much closer to what I wanted, but I've not been able to finish it off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea was the right one. With

$$g(w) = \frac{1}{M}\cdot f\left(\varphi_a(w)\right),$$

you have $\lvert g(w)\rvert \leqslant \lvert w\rvert$ by the Schwarz lemma. That translates to $$\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant M \left\lvert \varphi_a^{-1}(z)\right\rvert.$$

Now compute $\varphi_a^{-1}(z) = \varphi_a(z)$.